# Object potentially modified function

Tags: c++, oop, class, c++11

I have an object in C++.

Some of its functions make no change to the object and are qualified as being `const`.

Other functions do make a change to the object which should result in several values being recalculated.

My question is whether there exists in C++ or C++11 some special class method which is automagically called if a non-const method is used.

If not, why might this be?

Comment: What kind of special class method? O_o

Comment: I can't understand what are you asking for. Which method? For doing what?

Comment: You want a special class method which is automatically called when _any and all_ non-const methods are used?  That doesn't make much sense.  If you just want to recalculate when things are changed, _then recalculate when things are changed_.

Comment: No there isn't. If you need to recalculate things when things change then do what you want: recalculate things when things change. No special support needed.

Comment: @MooingDuck, it makes sense insofar as the recalculation may be complex and there may be a number of non-const methods which would invoke the computation. Such a function would ensure that the recalculation is performed as it should be and avoid repetition of code.

Comment: Regarding why not, because you assumedly wrote the code for the non-const function, and if it is called, you should know it (because your code is now executing).

Comment: @Richard: That makes sense, until one remembers that many non-const methods _don't actually change members_.  For instance, `std::vector::at` has a non-const version that doesn't change state.  Also `std::vector::begin`.

Comment: @Richard: but what is your goal? I can't understand that.

Comment: @Richard: this "special" function would be automatically called every time a non-const function was called. So add a `recalc()` function in your class and have every non-const method call it immediately before exiting. This implements the *exact* semantics you describe.

Comment: @akappa: Sounds like his class has a cached "hash", and whenever a member changes, he needs to update the hash too.  He's asking if there's a way to do this automatically.

Comment: @MooingDuck: wow, how did you infer that? it's absolutely unclear (and unstated) that this is the point.

Comment: @MooingDuck, the class wraps an expensive integration where various parameters of the system of equations are set via accessors. The integrator can cache its final state, but must be aware if a recalculation needs to be done.

Comment: @akappa: Sorry if I wasn't clear, I have no idea what he's doing.  But I was able to easily think of at least the one "hash" situation where the question makes sense, there's probably many more situations where this question would make sense.

Comment: Obviously, @NikBougalis, but my question is whether there is a means to avoid potentially missing adding this piece of code in an important place by using a language feature designed for that purpose.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that no, the language doesn't have anything to support it directly.

You could still do at least a little to centralize the code to keep track of whether your parameters have changed or not. For example, you could write a small template, something like this:

```
template <class T>
class param {
    T value_;
    bool clean_;
public:
    param(T v) : value_(v), clean_(false) {}

    param &operator=(param &other) { value_ = other.value; clean_ = false; return *this; }

    param &operator=(T const &t) { value_ = t; clean_ = false; return *this; }

    operator T() { return value_; }    

    void clean() { clean_ = true; }

    bool isclean() { return clean_; }
};
```

Then you'd have something like:

```
class integrator { 
    double value;
    param<double> a, b, c;

    double calculate_value(double a, double b, double c);

public:
    double operator()() { 
        if (a.isclean() && b.isclean() && c.isclean())
            return value;
        value = calculate_value(a, b, c);
        a.clean();
        b.clean();
        c.clean();
        return value;
    }
};
```

This doesn't automate the *entire* process, but does let you isolate the code so only the  function that uses the parameters needs to keep track of whether they're current -- the rest of the code can just assign values, and when they do the values are marked as dirty automatically.